# Calculate exact time of Solar midnight

Tags: astronomy, solar-system

I want to calculate real time of midnight (Solar midnight), but I am unable to find any formula or algorithm for that. I have times of sunrises and sunsets for every day of year. How can I get Solar midnight times from them?

Thank you all.

Comment: The midpoint in time between sunrise and sunset should be a good approximation. It was even the roman definition of midnight (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight).

Comment: related: [Local solar time function from UTC and longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13314626/4279) gives answer for the opposite direction: real time -> solar time. [Compute shadow length using PyEphem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5720633/4279) demonstrates how to find semi-programmatically the next (real) time from `sun_altitude(time) = known_altitude` equation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe finding the [Julian date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) will help you.  Julian days are used for astronomical purposes.  Every day midnight occurs exactly when the J.D. (Julian date) is *.5. So you can convert the J.D. to U.T. (Universal time) and then to your local time.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer, the Julian date does not depend on the local longitude as the solar midnight does. From the Wikipedia link: Julian Day Number (JDN) is the integer assigned to a whole solar day in the Julian day count starting from noon Universal time"

Answer (score 1):

The formula for calculating the Local Time equivalent for Local Solar Time is $LST=LT+\frac{TC}{60}$, where $TC$ is the Time Correction factor $TC=4(Longitude-LSTM)+EoT$. $LSTM$ is the Local Solar Time Meridian, calculated by $15º-ΔT_{GMT}$, where $ΔT_{GMT}$ is the difference, in hours, from GMT. (For instance, here on the east coast of the US, this value is -4 in the summer and -5 in the winter.) $EoT$ is the Equation of Time, $EoT=9.87sin(2B)-7.53cos(B)-1.5sin(B)$, where $B=\frac{360}{365}((day\ of\ year)-81)$.

If you rearrange that first equation to calculate $LT$ in terms of $LST$, you'll get $LT=LST-\frac{TC}{60}$. Set $LST$ to 12 to calculate solar noon and 24 to calculate solar midnight.

Equations from [here](http://pveducation.org/pvcdrom/2-properties-sunlight/solar-time).